# How does one render jQuery Mobile UI Object post page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have some HTML that I'm generating using JS on the client side. I'd still like to apply the style and functionality of jQuery Mobile UI to those objects as well. I can't seem to figure out how though...

Say I generate a:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Choose shipping method:</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And want to render it via jQuery Mobile UI inside a page... how would one do that?

I know with standard jQuery UI I'd just have to make a call along the lines of:

```
$("#select-choice-1").buttonset();
```

Is there something like this for jQuery Mobile UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE!**

Yeah! The new implementation with event just landed!

http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/07/22/jquery-mobile-team-update-week-of-july-18th/

Now in beta2 there will be a `create` event that triggered on an element will cause its rendering.

I will update the faq when beta2 ships.

Find the topmost element you add to DOM and call `.page()` on it.
This question in fact duplicates a lot of other questions tagged jquery-mobile, therefore I created a shot tutorial not to describe it again every time.

See first post here: http://jquerymobiledictionary.dyndns.org/faq.html

Comment: If you are refreshing just a single component it's ok to use the specific finction for that element. Otherwise you can use `.page()` that analyzes the DOM element and uses all avaliable widgets automagically :)

Comment: If called upon pagebeforecreate it fails which is understandable, if on pagecreate you go for a recursive loop ride. I wrote my own enhance() function to take care of this issue... elaborated on my other answer below.

Comment: Any chance you could provide an example or link...? Best yet if you put it up as an answer I'll up-vote it and give it the answer check...

Comment: OMG... what a mess... I just posted something that isn't true :( The event will not be implemented because there's a solution based on already avaliable stuff. I'll make some notes and post them. [removed my comment up there so as not to confuse people]

Comment: no worries, thanks for coming back and updating... :) as far as the notes you speak of, take your time, but they would be highly appreciated...

Comment: All's well that ends well. The event was implemented and it will be out in beta2! :) Just wait a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If called upon pagecreate

```
$('#page').live('pagecreate',function(event){
    $('#elem_container').page();
});
```

you go for a recursive loop ride. I wrote my own enhance() function to take care of this issue.

```
$('#page').live('pagecreate',function(event){
    enhance($('#elem_container'));
});
```

The function is basically just condensed the code below...

```
function enhance(dis){
    dis.find( "[type='radio'], [type='checkbox']" ).checkboxradio();
    dis.find( "button, [type='button'], [type='submit'], [type='reset'], [type='image']" ).not( ".ui-nojs" ).button();
    dis.find( "input, textarea" ).not( "[type='radio'], [type='checkbox'], button, [type='button'], [type='submit'], [type='reset'], [type='image']" ).textinput();
    dis.find( "input, select" ).filter( "[data-role='slider'], [data-type='range']" ).slider();
    dis.find( "select:not([data-role='slider'])" ).selectmenu();
}
```

**Older Post:**

After digging around the jQuery mobile file I finally figured it out... quite easy actually...

```
$("#select-choice-3").selectmenu();
```

And here's the chunk of code I dug this up in...

```
_enchanceControls: function() {
    var o = this.options;
    // degrade inputs to avoid poorly implemented native functionality
    this.element.find( "input" ).each(function() {
        var type = this.getAttribute( "type" );
        if ( o.degradeInputs[ type ] ) {
            $( this ).replaceWith(
                $( "<div>" ).html( $(this).clone() ).html()
                    .replace( /type="([a-zA-Z]+)"/, "data-type='$1'" ) );
        }
    });

    // enchance form controls
    this.element
        .find( "[type='radio'], [type='checkbox']" )
        .checkboxradio();

    this.element
        .find( "button, [type='button'], [type='submit'], [type='reset'], [type='image']" )
        .not( ".ui-nojs" )
        .button();

    this.element
        .find( "input, textarea" )
        .not( "[type='radio'], [type='checkbox'], button, [type='button'], [type='submit'], [type='reset'], [type='image']" )
        .textinput();

    this.element
        .find( "input, select" )
        .filter( "[data-role='slider'], [data-type='range']" )
        .slider();

    this.element
        .find( "select:not([data-role='slider'])" )
        .selectmenu();
}
```